# How to pick latest item per user from an array?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

For example, I have an array like this:

```
[ 
{  
  "data": "some data",
  "user": "A",
  "createdAt":"2016-12-24",
},
{
  "data": "some data2",
  "user": "B",
  "createdAt":"2016-12-24",
},
{
  "data": "some data3",
  "user": "A",
  "createdAt":"2016-12-25",
},
{
  "data": "some data4",
  "user": "A",
  "createdAt":"2016-12-23",
},
{
  "data": "some data5",
  "user": "B",
  "createdAt":"2016-12-25",
},
{
  "data": "some data6",
  "user": "C",
  "createdAt":"2016-12-24",
},
]
```

I only need the latest created item per one user, so I need an array like this:

```
[ 
{
  "data": "some data3",
  "user": "A",
  "createdAt":"2016-12-25",
},
{
  "data": "some data5",
  "user": "B",
  "createdAt":"2016-12-25",
},
{
  "data": "some data6",
  "user": "C",
  "createdAt":"2016-12-24",
},
]
```

How can I do it with underscore or lodash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lodash provides the [`orderBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#orderBy) and [`uniqBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#uniqBy) methods.

The key is to order by `user` then by `createdAt` in descending order. Since `createdAt` is a `Date` it needs to be treated as such. Conveiniently, the `orderBy` method allows one to specify either the property to order by or a function to evaluate (which returns the object to order by, in this case `Date`).

```js
var data = [{
      "data": "some data",
      "user": "A",
      "createdAt": "2016-12-24",
    }, {
      "data": "some data2",
      "user": "B",
      "createdAt": "2016-12-24",
    }, {
      "data": "some data3",
      "user": "A",
      "createdAt": "2016-12-25",
    }, {
      "data": "some data4",
      "user": "A",
      "createdAt": "2016-12-23",
    }, {
      "data": "some data5",
      "user": "B",
      "createdAt": "2016-12-25",
    }, {
      "data": "some data6",
      "user": "C",
      "createdAt": "2016-12-24",
    }],
    sorted = _.orderBy(
      data,
      ['user', function(d) {
        return new Date(d.createdAt)
      }],
      ['asc', 'desc'] // 'desc' orders by date descending
    ),
    uniqued = _.uniqBy(sorted, 'user');

console.log(uniqued);
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution in plain Javascript with a hash table and a check for a later `createdAt`.

```js
var data = [{ "data": "some data", "user": "A", "createdAt": "2016-12-24", }, { "data": "some data2", "user": "B", "createdAt": "2016-12-24", }, { "data": "some data3", "user": "A", "createdAt": "2016-12-25", }, { "data": "some data4", "user": "A", "createdAt": "2016-12-23", }, { "data": "some data5", "user": "B", "createdAt": "2016-12-25", }, { "data": "some data6", "user": "C", "createdAt": "2016-12-24", }],
    result = data.reduce(function (hash) {
        return function (r, a) {
            if (!(a.user in hash)) {
                hash[a.user] = r.push(a) - 1;
                return r;
            }
            if (r[hash[a.user]].createdAt < a.createdAt) {
                r[hash[a.user]] = a;
            }
            return r;
        };
    }(Object.create(null)), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: First time I have come across code I don't understand completely that works AND is good clean code.  From what I can see, there is no real loop at the script level --  is this kind of like the LINQ equivalent but in JavaScript ?  all the data is pushed to the method via `reduce` and the method acts recursively ?

Comment: @SamuelJackson, basically it uses a closure over `hash` and a callback, which is called for every element of `data` and this is represented by `a` in the callback. the result is collected in `r` and returned for every loop. while the callback is called for every item, it is not a recursive call, because it does not call itself.

Comment: Very sexy piece of javascript.  Thank you for the information.   By recursion, I meant it passes the data to that method for each item in the array, and returns the results.  In this way, it is similar to .NET's LINQ.   I love it  <3

Answer (score 1):

with plain javascript, you can do it like this

```js
var myArray = [ 
    {  
          "data": "some data",
          "user": "A",
          "createdAt":"2016-12-24",
    },
    {
          "data": "some data2",
          "user": "B",
          "createdAt":"2016-12-24",
    },
    {
          "data": "some data3",
          "user": "A",
          "createdAt":"2016-12-25",
    },
    {
          "data": "some data4",
          "user": "A",
          "createdAt":"2016-12-23",
    },
    {
          "data": "some data5",
          "user": "B",
          "createdAt":"2016-12-25",
    },
    {
          "data": "some data6",
          "user": "C",
          "createdAt":"2016-12-24",
    },
] 



function getLatestItems(itemArray) {
    var latestItemPerUser = {}, latesItems = [], newDate, oldDate;

    for(var i = 0, l = itemArray.length; i < l; ++i) {
        if(!latestItemPerUser[itemArray[i].user]) {
            latestItemPerUser[itemArray[i].user] = itemArray[i];
        } else {
            newDate = new Date(itemArray[i].createdAt);
            oldDate = new Date(latestItemPerUser[itemArray[i].user].createdAt);

            if(oldDate < newDate) {
                latestItemPerUser[itemArray[i].user] = itemArray[i];
            }
        }
    }

    for(var item in latestItemPerUser) {
        latesItems.push(latestItemPerUser[item]);
    }

    return latesItems;
}

console.log(getLatestItems(myArray));
```

Comment: Good solution for pure javascript. Upvoted for those who come here in the future looking for a way to do it without additional libraries. The `sort()` method in the [prototype extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to javascript (built in most browsers now), can speed up the sort method on key, making this arguably bit faster.

Comment: Thanks, @SamuelJackson. On second thought, we could get rid of the Date object if we can sure the "createdAt" property always comes with "YYYY-MM-DD" format.

Moreover, if we can use ES2015, the code would look like

Comment: `
    function getLatestItemsES6(itemArray) {
        let latestItems = [];

        for(var item of itemArray.sort((a, b) => a.createdAt < b.createdAt)) {
            if(!latestItems.some((obj) => obj.user === item.user)) {
                latestItems.push(item);
            }
        }
            return latestItems;
    }
`